# how to make a xpath-search in two stages?

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x, lxml, lxml.html

please help fix sript.

```
import lxml.html
import requests

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""<html>
 <body>
   <div class="wrap">
       <span class="one">one</span>
       <span class="two">two</span>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
""")

#first search
result1 = doc.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]')
print(result1)

#second search
result2 = result1.xpath('//span/text()')
print(result2)
```

I need the script to search for text in two stages:

- Step 1: Search tree 'div.wrap',
- Step 2: Search for text elements.

The result should be a list of 
['one', 'two']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join two xpath expressions into one:

```
>>> doc.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]/span/text()')
['one', 'two']
```

If you need to do it in two stages:

```
>>> result1 = doc.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]')
>>> result1
[<Element div at 0x2cf5ba0>]
>>> result1[0].xpath('.//span/text()')
['one', 'two']
```

If `result1` can be multiple item list, you need some kind of loop:

```
>>> [div.xpath('.//span/text()') for div in result1]
[['one', 'two']]
>>> [txt for div in result1 for txt in div.xpath('.//span/text()')]
['one', 'two']
```

Comment: I think the 2nd XPath expression needs to be relative: `[div.xpath('.//span/text()') for div in result1]`

Comment: @pault., Thank you for comment. I updated the answer accordingly.